# Behaviour test using parametrised Spock framework

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a set of behavior tests which should result in the same  outcome

```
def 'behaviour tests for route A'() {
 when:
   doA();

 then:
  data == 'Hi'
}

def 'behaviour tests for route B'() {
 when:
   doB();

 then:
  data == 'Hi'
}

void doA(){
 ...
}

void doB(){
 ...
}
```

the code looks ugly I would have preferred to use parametrized testing. something alongside this:

```
@Unroll
def 'behaviour tests for route #name'() {
     when:
       route
    
     then:
      data == 'Hi'

     where:
      name | route
      'A'  | doA()
      'B'  | doB()
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use closures to extract the code that you want executed in the `when` block.

```
class ClosureSpec extends Specification {

  @Unroll
  def 'behaviour tests for route #name'() {
    when:
    def data = route()

    then:
    data == 'Hi'

    where:
    name | route
    'A'  | { doA() }
    'B'  | { doB() }
  }

  def doA() {
    return 'Hi'
  }

  def doB() {
    return 'Hi'
  }
}
```

or you could use groovys dynamic nature to pass in the method name

```
class DynamicSpec extends Specification {

  @Unroll
  def 'behaviour tests for route #name'() {
    when:
    def data = this."do$name"()

    then:
    data == 'Hi'

    where:
    name | route
    'A'  | _
    'B'  | _
  }

  def doA() {
    return 'Hi'
  }

  def doB() {
    return 'Hi'
  }
}
```

Depending on the use-case I'd go with the closure, but the dynamic method name has its uses, especially if you want to pass in parameters.